# React.js - how to pass event handlers to deeply nested component without props drilling?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I have the structure of components (nested) that seems like this:

- Container

  - ComponentA

    - ComponentB

      - ComponentC(want to handle event here with state that lives on container)

Do I need to pass as props all the way from Container, ComponentA, ComponentB and finally ComponentC to have this handler? Or is there another way like using Context API?

I'm finding a bit hard to handle events with react.js vs vue.js/angular.js because of this.

Comment: This is what context is for.

Comment: @estus even for events??

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's even handler or anything else you're passing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using either [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (as you mentioned) or [Higher Order Components (HoC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Answer (score 0):

Context Api is your data center. You put all the data and click events that your application needs  here and then with "Consumer" method you fetch them in any component regardless of how nested it is. Here is a basic example:

```
context.js //in your src folder.

import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";
import { storeProducts } from "./data"; //imported the data from data.js
const ProductContext = createContext(); //created context object
class ProductProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    products: storeProducts,
    };
render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
//we pass the data via value prop. anything here is accessible
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          addToCart: this.addToCart //I wont use this in the example because it would 
 be very long code, I wanna show you that, we pass data and event handlers here!
        }}
      >
  // allows all the components access the data provided here
        {this.props.children},
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;
export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer };
```

Now we set up our data center with .Consumer and .Provider methods so we can access 
   here via "ProductConsumer" in our components. Let's say you want to display all your products in your home page.
   ProductList.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Product from "./Product";
import { ProductConsumer } from "../context";

class ProductList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
<React.Fragment>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <ProductConsumer>
       //we fetch data here, pass the value as an argument of the function
                {value => {
                  return value.products.map(product => {
                    return <Product key={product.id}  />;
                  });
                }}
              </ProductConsumer>
            </div>
          </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default ProductList;
```

This is the logic behind the Context Api. It sounds scary but if you know the logic it is very simple. Instead of creating your data and events handlers inside of each component and prop drilling which is a big headache, just put data and your event handlers here and orchestrate them.

I hope it helps.