# Pass event through nested components bottom to top

Tags: reactjs

While this question has been asked before I did not find an answer. I have components nested to the level of great grandchild and I don't know how to get the data from the bottom to the top.

```
<Parent/>
  <Child/>
    <GrandChild/>
      <GreatGrandChild/>
```

See an example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/9aex32cy/34/)

The great grandchild is a form and I want the input data to get to the parent at the top. I had it working when it was just nested one level deep, but now that it is deeply nested it does not work. I'm not sure how to even pass the event up two levels.

I've heard using redux is possible but I wonder if there is a way to avoid it. Or, how do I avoid the nesting? Even through they are all actually separate components should I just move them into one big component? This might work but seems like bad practice?

Comment: For this I prefer to use the Context API

Comment: Thanks for tip. I am looking at it now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js - how to pass event handlers to deeply nested component without props drilling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820155/react-js-how-to-pass-event-handlers-to-deeply-nested-component-without-props-d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simplified, you could just pass the function through all the components:

```
class GreatGrandChild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <input onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
        <h2>I'm the GreatGrandChild</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class GrandChild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>I'm the GrandChild</h2>
        <GreatGrandChild onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <GrandChild onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
        <h2>I'm the child</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class Top extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  handleChildchange = (e) => {
    console.log('child event on parent')
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <Child onChange={this.handleChildchange}/>
        <h2>I'm the parent</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Top />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: Yes - But be aware, it is fore sure not the most elegant way. It is more elegant to use Context API / HoCs..

Comment: My situation is simple enough for this to suffice. However for the future I will investigate the context API.

Answer (score 1):

Redux is overkill for simple passing of props. You can pass props down through each child but it's easier to use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) like so:

## Parent Component:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext('default');
export MyContext;

class Parent extends React.Component {
    myFunction() {
        //Do something here
    }

    render() {
         return (
            <MyContext.Provider value={this.myFunction}>
                <ChildComponent />
            </MyContext.Provider>
         );
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

## Child Component:

```
import { MyContext } from './Parent';

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { myFunction } = this.context;
        return (
            <div onClick={myFunction}>Click Me!</div>
        );
    }
}

ChildComponent.contextType = MyContext;
```

You can use the context as deep as you'd like, as long as you import it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass a callback down from the parent via the props and make Sure it's passed all the way down to where you need it.

Comment: Can't since I'm on mobile take a look at the new answers or look at how it's done in the offical tutorial you'd have to do the same thing but twice (once when passing the callback to the child and again to get it to the grandchild )https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

You also can pass props to your each child component in nesting and whenever values changed,  you can call a parent function (nested) to get latest values in parent.